# Connection error: TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})

Tags: java, python, cassandra

I am using ubantu 16.04 and Cassandra while calling the 'cqlsh' command on the terminal it is giving me the error.

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1':TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})
```

while Nodetool status is up and running

```
   Datacenter: datacenter1
   =======================
   Status=Up/Down
   |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
   --  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                                               Rack
   UN  127.0.0.1  270.72 KiB  256          100.0%                  89a6fc91-1e25-41bf-b633-95b53292a2b3  rack1
```

I checked this error and found the compatibility problem with python 2.7.12 which is default in ubantu 16.04.

Before it was running find but suddenly it start asking me the permission for read and write on the the log in cassandra and after that it is running but cqlsh is not working.

But i am able to read and create tables from eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try `path/to/cqlsh HOST`

In your scenario `HOST = 127.0.0.1`

Comment: I have tried but thing is not working  cqlsh 127.0.0.1
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})

Comment: I think the real problem is not that it is not going to resolve the address but something different is happing

Comment: What the Cassandra version ?

Comment: cassandra version is 3.6